# tkinter script doesn't create window

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run this simple script I don't see a window created:

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

l1=label(window,text="Title")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

l2=label(window,text="Author")
l2.grid(row=0,column=2)

l3=label(window,text="Year")
l3.grid(row=1,column=0)

l4=label(window,text="ISBN")
l4.grid(row=1,column=2)



window.mainloop()
```

I've tried it with python 2.7 and python 3.6 and I get the same results.

Comment: When I run the code I get the error `NameError: name 'label' is not defined` which is not surprising. The name of the class is `Label`, not `label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure any time you are creating a widget you use a capital letter at the start of the word because all of tkinters widgets are like this.

Frame, Button, Label and so on. This is the problem you are having.

You should be able to figure this out with a trackback error.

I would install Eclipse with pydev for python or py charm IDE so you can have
fault detection that will point out issues with your code before you even run it.

So Change all your instances of `label` to `Label`

Comment: @Novel Pythons default IDLE has always returned `syntax error` with no trackback for me. Maybe the command line returns trackback but my IDLE interface does not.

Comment: @Novel I am testing it now and some errors do not return a trackback but just syntax error or invalid syntax where others return a track back. I will edit my answer.

Comment: IDLE catches syntax error specifically because it highlights the position of the error in the editor. And OP did not have a syntax error.

Comment: @Novel I had a problem specifically with IDLE when I first started learning python. [Here is the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677507/syntax-error-at-the-end-of-a-while-loop). This is why I have stated that the IDLE did not provide a trackback though looking back there was not a lot of time spent on IDLE before moving to Eclipse so I should have looked into it further before providing my answer. I have updated my answer and removed the inaccurate information on trackbacks. Thanks for pointing it out.